# How can I lay out two <div>s on one line, and have one centre-aligned (relative to the entire line) and the other right-aligned?

Tags: html, css

I want to display 2 divs in a single line. I have a parent div and two child divs.I want to keep the width of first child div and parent div equal. So the header(label of first child div) displays always middle position of parent div and I want to display the second child div at the right side in the same line of parent div.(Condition is always label of first child div should display middle of parent div). Here is the [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/digantapatra/s4KKk/).

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question. If the width of parent div and 1st child div is the same, then other div will adjust itself somewhere else (parent div is full)

Comment: Can you provide the snap in which design you want using paint brush ?

Comment: Why are you using `<label>` elements, I don't see any input fields associated with them.  A header or paragraph tag might make more sense.  Also, for your right hand div, are you looking for a box of text or a single line of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were styling this header section for a website, and I wanted some flexibility in styling the various elements, here is out I would start.

For my HTML:

```
<div class="head">
    <div class="innerfirst">
         <h1>ABCDEF GHIJ</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="innersecond">
        <label>RIGHT1</label>
        <label>RIGHT2</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would put the page title in a `<h1>` tag so that I can adjust font-size, padding, background color and so on.  In fact, you could add a tag line below the title line and various background images.  Having `.innerfirst` and `h1` gives you quite a bit of flexibility.

The `<label>` tags don't make sense semantically in this context, but perhaps you will have have input fields later like a search box.

For the CSS:

```
.head {
    background-color:#2191C0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 85px;
    position: relative;
}
```

The above is fine, set `position: relative` so that you can use absolute positioning for one of the child elements.  The fixed height is a good idea, makes it easier to adjust elements vertically.

```
.innerfirst {
}
.innerfirst h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #FCFCFC;
    padding-top: 10px; /* You could also use a margin... */
}
```

By default, `.innerfirst` will have 100% width since it is an in-flow block element, same with the `h1` element.  You can center the text within `h1`, and adjust color, padding and margin as needed.

```
.innersecond {
    border: 2px solid lightgray;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%; /* Set this or by default it will shrink-to-fit content */
    height: 61px; /* Set this or by default it will shrink-to-fit content */
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

What you could do is create a box of text and absolutely position it to the right.  It is a good idea
to set a height and width otherwise, as a result of the absolute positioning, the `div` will shrink to fit the content, which is sometimes useful.  The top and right offsets will position the `.innersecond` to the top-right of the parent container because you set `position: relative` in `.head`.

```
.innersecond label {
    display: block; /* optional if you want block behavior */
    border: 1px dotted white;
}
```

Finally, if you want the `label` tags to behave like blocks, use `display: block` and style according to you design requirements.

For reference, demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/qpb9P/

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s4KKk/1/). Read up on the `display` property!

Comment: I didn't know `display:inline` and `position:fixed` combined would have that effect. How does it work?

Comment: position: fixed; is only removing the content from document flow in this case

Comment: @xec: I think it is needed - the OP wants `innerfirst`'s text centre-aligned in relation to the entire width of the parent `<div>`. If `innersecond` is in document flow and set to `display:inline` like `innerfirst`, then `innerfirst`'s text will move a bit to the left.

Comment: Did you read about the `display` property? Why do you use `display: inline` instead of `display: inline-block`?

Comment: @Osh: Thanks for reply but alignment of two labels in second div child is not displaying proper position when resizeing the window size.

Comment: @ Paul D. Waite: Always text center-aligned in relation to the entire width of the parent <div>. But displaying second div would not effect the align of first child div. Am I quite clear??